# Python - How to convert entity properties from form post

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am aware of how to convert the strings posted from my form to some of the common types, eg (Boolean and Integer):

```
age = int(self.request.get("age")) #convert to integer
opt_in = self.request.get("opt_in") == 'on' #convert to boolean
```

My questions is how about how to convert to some of the less common types, ie 
1. EmailProperty
2. FloatProperty
3. PhoneNumberProperty
4. DateProperty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged your question with [app-engine-ndb](/questions/tagged/app-engine-ndb), but the `EmailProperty` and `PhoneNumberProperty` are actually `db` properties, not `ndb` ones:

- [`ndb` Property Types](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#types)
- [`db` Types and Property Classes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses)

They have Unicode sort order, so I guess you could use `StringProperty` for them, no conversion needed.

For `DateProperty` you need a `datetime.date()` value type, see [How to convert a time string in a Google AppEngine db.TimeProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263875/how-to-convert-a-time-string-in-a-google-appengine-db-timeproperty/42264502#42264502)

So you just need to convert your string representation to a `datetime.date()`.

For `FloatProperty` see [Parse String to Float or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int).

Comment: Interesting. I am still trying to understand the difference of ndb vs db. The Google docs tend to reference both interchangeably. I know there is a table of db to ndb namespaces/parameters to migrate. I will look more into this thanks Dan.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852442/pros-and-cons-of-db-and-ndb-in-google-app-engine/12855111#12855111 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645572/app-engine-difference-between-ndb-and-datastore/23646875#23646875